# How to edit OpenCart code?

Tags: opencart

I need to edit OpenCart code, but I can't find where is it... In catalog/view/theme/journal2/template/affiliate/transaction.tpl there is **Date added** `<td class="text-left"><?php echo $column_date_added; ?></td>`. Where could I found code of **$column_date_added** to edit it? Where are year, month and day? I need to delete year.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open This file:

```
catalog\controller\affiliate\transaction.php
```

find:

```
'date_added'  => date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($result['date_added']))
```

change to:

```
'date_added'  => date('d/m', strtotime($result['date_added']))
```

It's better to use [Ocmod](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Modification-System) or [vQmod](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod) for modify Opencart files.